# nginx passing back custom header

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have the following example

```
           location / {
                    proxy_read_timeout 2000;
                    proxy_next_upstream error;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_pass_header X_CUSTOM_HEADER;
                    proxy_redirect off;
                    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                    proxy_pass https://prod;
                    break;
            }
```

Now when i use the following curl line

```
curl --head -H "X_CUSTOM_HEADER: foo" http://domain.com/api/test
```

Now that does not work.. the apache/php on the backend doesn't see the header. If I bypass nginx it works

```
curl --head -H "X_CUSTOM_HEADER: foo" http://web1.domain.com/api/test
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use [`underscores_in_headers on`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) directive which is off by default.

Comment: This info saves me hours.

Comment: I would gladly buy you a refreshing beverage.

Comment: you sir, are a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `proxy_set_header` for all headers you wish to forward to the backend servers. So instead of `proxy_pass_header ...` line:

```
proxy_set_header X_CUSTOM_HEADER $http_x_custom_header;
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't set the header correctly, If i replace $http_x_custom_header with "foo" it works

Comment: I'm not sure why it didn't work for @Mike but it did work for me. I am using X-Forwarded-Proto with $http_x_forwarded_proto.

Answer (score 2):

The above didn't work for me either so I used `proxy_pass_header`.  See the  [Nginx Wiki about proxy_pass_header here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass_header).

If your custom header is `device_id` add `proxy_pass_header device_id;` to your Proxy block.

If you are using customheaders with an underscore in it (like I am) be sure to make sure you have `underscores_in_headers on` in your Nginx Config.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was pulling my hair out.... Your post relieved me....

Answer (score 2):

By default the nginx forwards all the ( **proxy_pass_request_headers on;**) the header to the backend server. But if your request header ( may be custom header) includes underscore ( _ ) in the header name then nginx blocks those headers.

```
Ex: authenticate_type, cdn_enable.
```

To enable Nginx to pass all or the custom requested header to the backend turn on the underscore option on.

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```