# nginx proxy pass removing header SM_USER from java spring rest client request

Tags: nginx, java, springframework

We are using nginx as a proxy for a java application (both in docker containers, but that's probably not relevant). When we try to reach the java application via a rest client a specific header, SM_USER gets lost within the proxy-pass. Strange thing is: if we use CURL or PHP Zend Framework or a Firefox rest add-on to do a request the proxy pass configuration works. But if we use a Java Spring rest client or soapUI
the header gets lost. If we bypass the proxy it works from Java/soapUI as well.

We use the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name devrest.example.com;
  root /devrestserver;
  underscores_in_headers on;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_pass http://devrest:8080;
  }
}
```

As you can see we use
    underscores_in_headers on;
and explicitly set
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
in the configuration.

A tcpdump before nginx takes over shows us the SM_USER header is reaching the server:

```
GET /resource/RoomType/ HTTP/1.1
    Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
    Content-Type: application/json
    SM_USER: atnqtjrce0cjfve0fbjbsov2ff
    Accept-Language: de
    User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_71
    Host: devrest.example.com
    Connection: keep-alive
```

A tcpdump within the docker network (between the nginx proxy and the application) shows that the header dissapeared:

```
GET /resource/RoomType/ HTTP/1.0
    X-Forwarded-Host: devrest.example.com
    X-Forwarded-Server: devrest.example.com
    X-Forwarded-For: 78.132.28.121
    Host: devrest:8080
    Connection: close
    Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
    Content-Type: application/json
    Accept-Language: de
    User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_71
```

I also tried

```
proxy_pass_header SM_USER;
```

as recommended at the following link
[nginx passing back custom header](https://serverfault.com/questions/297225/nginx-passing-back-custom-header)

and I tried explicitly renaming the header by using the following:

```
proxy_set_header X-siteminderuser $http_sm_user;
```

which worked totally fine when doing the CURL request but didn't show up at all using Java. It seems the SM_USER is filtered out even before $http_... variable takes effect.

If I rename the header in the java rest client and use

```
proxy_set_header SM_USER $http_x_siteminder_user;
```

it gets through but unfortunately it is very hard to get this changed in the original java rest client (which is a software from another company), so I would really appreciate any suggestions how I could get the SM_USER header passed through the nginx proxy. Can you help us please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have another server section above this?

[This thread](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,161404,161423#msg-161423) on the nginx forum suggests that it only pays attention to the `underscores_in_headers` directive in the first server section.

Comment: Also appears [in the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers). I would advise using the directive at the `http` block level to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you both, it works! I really had different server sections using the same directive and sorry that I overlooked that sentence in the docs.. But I don't fully get why it behaved differently whether we used curl or the java engine (and always the same depending on the client we used even on different machines)

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps the curl client was hitting the default server block? (using the IP instead of host name? IPv6?). BTW I can see nginx is using HTTP/1.0 for the upstream request, you might get better performance if you force that to be 1.1.